# What is a suitable database system to store a SNS's activities log?

Tags: database, statistics, logging, analytics

I was in a subject with my senior executives about choosing a suitable database system to store a SNS's all log activities, including things like in Facebook : posts log (who post, when), like, image, link, etc. The main point is the databases are going to very huge (1 billion in 3 months I estimate), and there will be a analytics system based on those log like google analytics (query to count or sum up, total, etc). So what database system will you choose and why? Just discussing. :)

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Infobright has an open source analytic database that you would be interested in.  Download it from www.infobright.org, look for the open source ICE